# separate Sign In for user and admin rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am building forum application using rails 4.2.I have two user roles in my application that is "user" and "admin" like below

enum :role=> {:user=>0, :admin=>1}

right now there is single Sign In in my application which is provided by devise gem. I need separate Sign In in my application so that i can provide separate Sign In for user and admin.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise works out of the box with one login view that can sign in both regular users and admins users.  If you want a separate path for admin users such as /admin just add that route in your routes.rb file and have it point to the devise login page.

With my apps I just use s simple redirect as such:

```
get '/admin', to: redirect('/users/sign_in')
```

and then I have my controller recognize the user type is admin, which now loads the admin section.

Comment: If it is the right answer and works for you please mark it as the correct answer and +1 it.  That is the correct way to say thanks.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.  If you want to ever up-vote or down-vote an answer or question you do so by clicking the appropriate arrows that are above (or below) the counter.  You can see the counter to the left of my answer.  I suggest you view Stack Overflows tutorials on appropriate use of voting.